# Where does the "page" GET parameter come from?

Tags: django, django-models

I am a beginner in Django, and I am really thoughtful about how things really work under the Django hood. I am currently implementing pagination in my web app.

Take a look at this view.py file:

```
def post_list(request):

    object_list = Post.published.all(); # '.published' is a manager.

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3); # 3 posts in each page.
    page = request.GET.get("page");

    try:

        posts = paginator.page(page);

    except PageNotAnInteger:

        posts = paginator.page(1);

    except EmptyPage:

        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages);

    return render(request, "post/list.html", {"page": page, "posts": posts});
```

Isn't request.GET a dictionary object containing all the the GET request parameters that are in the url, and the .get() method used to return the value
for the given key inside the parameter? As my URL is currently just localhost:8000 when I start the application, why does it work if I pass the key "page"?

My list.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>My Blog</h1>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>  <!-- How does this absurl work?-->
    <p class="date">Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p> <!-- What does '.publish' print?-->
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
  <!-- The statement above is the little menu: "Page 1 of 2. Next" -->
  <!-- It also sends the 'page' variable as a GET parameter. -->

{% endblock %}
```

My pagination.html file:

```
<!-- This pagination template expects a paginator object. -->
<div class="pagination">

  <span class="step-links">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
      <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}


    <span class="current">
      Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}. <!-- what!? -->
    </span>

    {% if page.has_next %}
      <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}

  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. The phrase "how is it possible for Django to know that it should not display everything that it is supposed to" is logically inconsistent.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you very much for noticing.

Comment: You are catching the PageNotAnInteger exception and then passing 1 to the paginator.page function. Then you are catching an EmptyPage exception and it looks like a default/fallback value is being used.

Comment: To better understand your question, can you please explain what exactly you're confused about? Is it that you don't know where Django gets the key value pairs to populate the request.GET dictionary?

Comment: Alright. My question is: If "request.GET" is a dictionary populated with the GET request parameters, why can I use "page" as the key in "request.GET.get("page") if there is no "page" parameter in the GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are no parameters in the request (when you hit `http://localhost:8000` directly), the value of `page` will be `None`. That is the default behaviour of `request.GET.get()` when it can't find the key you're asking for - the same as a normal Python dictionary (because GET extends it).

```
# page will be None
page = request.GET.get("page")
```

This means that `None` is passed to `paginator.page()`:

```
try:
    # Passing None here
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
```

Which likely means (although we can't see the code of `paginagor`) that a `PageNotAnInteger` exception is raised, and thus a value of 1 is passed to `paginagor.page()`:

```
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)  # Raises PageNotAnInteger because None passed
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # Posts are retrieved for page 1
    posts = paginator.page(1)
```

The `posts` from the above call, and the value of `page` (still `None`) are then passed to the template.

```
return render(request, "post/list.html", {"page": page, "posts": posts});
```

The template `list.html` then iterates the posts and displays them.

Rather confusingly, when the `pagination.html` template is included, it defines a context variable called `page` to the current value of `posts`:

```
<!-- Pass the value of posts using a variable name of page -->
{% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
```

So the places where the `pagination.html` template refers to `page`, it is actually using the value of `posts`.

```
<!-- Really posts.number and posts.paginator.num_pages -->
Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
```

Hope that helps to explain things.

One other thing, you don't need to add a semi-colon to the end of every line in Python.